# Why do C arrays 'wrap around'

Tags: c

I recently started programming in C, and I noticed, that sometimes, when I accidentally pointed an array to '-1', the array would go to the last element. Why does this happen?

EDIT: As an example, I was building a forest fire model, and sometimes, when a burning tree was on the edge of the forest, new burning trees would pop up at the other edge of the forest, without throwing any errors

Comment: It shouldn't, and you shouldn't rely on this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **undefined behavior**.
The compiler is allow to make [demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

In practice, this will usually end up accessing the memory before the array, which may crash.

Comment: What if you have `char a[10][10];` and then access `a[1][-1]`? I think that's what the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze it _could_ be the last element of the previous row, but it's still undefined

Comment: @JanDvorak Right, I've found it in the standard (Annex J, Undefined Behavior, as usual): `— An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5])`.

Answer (score 2):

They don't. It is just that C does not check that you are stepping outside the array; and when you do, the results are unpredictable. Take a look at [this site](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c), check out the tutorials linked (oldish, but good). There is also a link to a tutorial on pointers and arrays in C.

C is a language designed for maximal performance, and thus assumes that the programmer knows exactly what she is doing. No training wheels, no safety net. Liberating when you are accustomed to this; frigthening until then. Keep at it, *understand* what is going on, and have fun.

Comment: The images on that site are broken in Chrome

Comment: I observe several pages of text with some broken images, mainly on the top. Maybe your browser hides images it doesn't understand?

Comment: @JanDvorak, Firefox here. And the site is _old_, and has always worked fine with all sorts of browsers. Try a text-only one like elinks?

Comment: the images have an empty `alt`, so they'll be hidden in text-only browsers

Comment: @JanDvorak Strange. Looking at the page source, there certainly are images. Never seen them...

Comment: The age might explain why they're using a [file format that has long faded from a de-facto standard to basically dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBM)

Comment: As a side note, I've never seen `<link rev="made" rel="made" href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com">` or [`<tt>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/tt) before

Comment: re "C is a language designed for maximal performance": Actually, I believe it originally simply provided a more user friendly syntactical sugar to the PDP-11 macro language. It so often appears to be equivalent to a machine language because, Surprise!, that is all it originally was.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, not really. It is the successor to a series of "system programming languages" (designed to _replace_ assembler for high-performance), BCPL and B (and even earlier ones), from before there was a PDP-11. Machines were limited, so the compiler couldn't do much, and because of its "systems" orientation by force the language does feel a bit "assemblerish".